# A question plus the answers more appropriate as an article

Tags: discussion

In [this](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/a-list-of-suitable-foods-for-a-long-hike/1669#1669) question that I asked, I am asking about a comprehensive list of some class of items. All answers contribute to the list, but no single answer can be selected as "most correct", unless it quotes all other answers.

I would like it best if the question + answers form some kind coherent article. What should I do to this end? As far as I read about the idea of stack exchange wiki, it is not a suitable alternative. Or is the discussion fine this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wiki can form a coherent article.  The discussion along the way is not only fine, but absolutely necessary.  The quality is formed by the community collaboration and can't really happen in absence of it.

" All answers contribute to the list, but no single answer can be selected as "most correct", unless it quotes all other answers." -- This basically defines the criteria for making this a community wiki.

The best way to make it "more coherent" is to edit the wiki answer to add in the elements you see are missing.